# How compile a user space program with kernel headers

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to test a usbfs device by using `ioctl`.
I need use `ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, &receive);`.
But `USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY` is defined in a kernel header, so I include some kernel file like that:

```
#include <linux/usb.h>
#include <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>
#include <asm/byteorder.h>
#include <linux/usb/ch9.h>
```

and compile it with `gcc -g -I /usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/ -o /home/madper/kernel/usb/select_for_usb /home/madper/kernel/usb/select_for_usb.c`

It said `#warning "Attempt to use kernel headers from user space, see http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders" [-Wcpp]`

And folled by lots of errors, so, What's the right way to use kernel headers?

```
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:21:2: error: unknown type name ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:36:2: error: unknown type name ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:37:33: error: ‘kernel_ulong_t’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:37:3: error: requested alignment is not an integer constant
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:119:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:141:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:154:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:168:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:179:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:187:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:195:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:200:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:227:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:260:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:314:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:341:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:366:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:413:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:433:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:444:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:479:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:508:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:540:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:551:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:566:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/usr/src/linux-3.4.4-2-pae/include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:582:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
/home/madper/kernel/usb/select_for_usb.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/madper/kernel/usb/select_for_usb.c:46:30: error: expected expression before ‘void’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't have to include kernel headers directly.  In some cases it is necessary and probably the best way to handle it is to grab a copy of the kernel headers and hack out just the parts you need.  But in this case I'm not sure I understand why you need kernel headers.  Why doesn't it work just to include `<linux/usbdevice_fs.h>`?

On all the systems I looked at (a couple of different Ubuntu systems and one RHEL 6 system) that file can be included from userspace and has the define of `USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY`.  I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>

int main()
{
    printf("USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY is %ld\n", USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY);
    return 0;
}
```

and I can build it cleanly and when I run it I get

```
USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY is 1074287885
```

so at least based on what you wrote above, you don't need any kernel headers for that ioctl define.  I suspect anything else you think you need for userspace USB stuff is similarly exported to userspace in a clean header.

Comment: thank you very much. And I tired to compile my code without kernel header. But when running it, I got an other error. And I think it's different from this question. So I creat a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574418/how-to-get-usbs-urb-info-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use kernel headers for user programs. Even if you do by some means it is strongly discouraged. Check the below link for more clarification.

http://lwn.net/Articles/113349/

If you do want to control usb devices from user space look at libusb.

Comment: Thank you. But I just need it one time. Just for test a device, so I don't care about the future change of kernel.  :)