# pmbus.h missing from /usr/include

Tags: linux, ubuntu, embedded-linux, i2c, dpkg

I'm trying to use pmbus.h in user space on ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. But the file is missing from /usr/include/ so I'm unable to access the files. Is there any library I need to use like for smbus to include headers? or any other way I can include this header for user space usage?
I did try what suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488328/how-to-get-appropriate-lib-package-name-for-a-specific-header-file) and try

> dpkg -S pmbus.h

But output was

> linux-headers-5.4.0-150-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-150-generic/include/config/pmbus.h
> linux-headers-5.4.0-148-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-148-generic/include/config/sensors/pmbus.h
> linux-headers-5.4.0-150-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-150-generic/include/config/sensors/pmbus.h
> linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-150: /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-150/include/linux/pmbus.h
> linux-headers-4.15.0-213-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-213-generic/include/config/sensors/pmbus.h
> linux-headers-4.15.0-213-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-213-generic/include/config/pmbus.h
> linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-148: /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-148/include/linux/pmbus.h
> linux-headers-4.15.0-213: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-213/include/linux/pmbus.h
> linux-headers-5.4.0-148-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-148-generic/include/config/pmbus.h

which is again under kernel headers.

Below command returns nothing

> sudo apt-file -x search '/pmbus.h$'

Comment: Package managers can typically search packages by file names.

Comment: What to expect and where to look depends on which Linux distro you are on. For Debian, for example, https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=pmbus.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I did try as explained in https://askubuntu.com/questions/488328/how-to-get-appropriate-lib-package-name-for-a-specific-header-file. But I see no results.

Comment: @tripleee Its ubuntu. Sorry I should have mentioned.

Comment: You already have the header as indicated by the `dpkg -S` output; you just need to update your include path to make it visible to the compiler. Please [edit] to show us an actual command which doesn't work; see also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Your `apt-file` command returns 362 results for me (albeit on Jammy, not Bionic). Did you forget `apt-file update`?

Comment: @tripleee . dpkg -S gives the headers that are under kernel headers. I'm directed not to use. Previously same issue was there with smbus.h. That i was able to get it under /usr/include/ by installing libi2c-dev. So, i was expecting the same with pmbus . And yes i have some error with apt-file update

Comment: We really don't know what advice you received about smbus earlier; do you have a link? Do you have a reason to not use the kernel headers?

Comment: @tripleee using kernel headers for user space application was raising some conflicts same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558671/how-compile-a-user-space-program-with-kernel-headers

Comment: This seems like one of those cases where you have to. There are no packages with this header file which are not kernel packages. The result will then nominally depend on which version of the kernel you compiled for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256275/discussion-between-demzys-and-tripleee).